# UITableView if(cell == null) error

Tags: objective-c

I have this problem with my code, I am trying to add textfields to my cells. And it worked! But when I tried again afterwards it didn't. I debugged a little with NSLog and came to the conclusion that cell wasn't = nil and therefore my code wasn't being run.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"Called1");
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        NSLog(@"Called?");
        UITextField *playerTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
        playerTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        playerTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        if([indexPath row] == 0) {
            playerTextField.placeholder = @"yoyo1";
            playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
            playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
        } else {
            playerTextField.placeholder = @"yoyo2";
            playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
            playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
            playerTextField.secureTextEntry = YES;
        }

        playerTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        playerTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        playerTextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
        playerTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        playerTextField.tag = 0;

        playerTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
        [playerTextField setEnabled: YES];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:playerTextField];

    }


    return cell;
}
```

The code `NSLog(@"Called?")` doesn't get called, but `NSLog(@"Called1")` does. Why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a little change:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"Called1");
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    NSLog(@"Called?");
    //And then the rest of your cell configuration code...
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code to this, the way you initialize table cells is not correct.

[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"]; if this line returns non-nil your code will not correctly initialize the table cell. The logic is to get a new table cell by either dequeuing or re-using after you allocated a suitable table cell decorate it the same way.

```
  -(UITableViewCell *)reuseTableViewCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier withIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        UITableViewCell * cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:identifier];

    return cell;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        NSLog(@"Called1");
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        if (cell == nil) {
             cell = [self reuseTableViewCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" withIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        NSLog(@"Called?");
        UITextField *playerTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
        playerTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        playerTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        if([indexPath row] == 0) {
            playerTextField.placeholder = @"yoyo1";
            playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
            playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
        } else {
            playerTextField.placeholder = @"yoyo2";
            playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
            playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
            playerTextField.secureTextEntry = YES;
        }

        playerTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        playerTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        playerTextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
        playerTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        playerTextField.tag = 0;

        playerTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
        [playerTextField setEnabled: YES];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:playerTextField];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: i don't get this, i give the answer earlier and get a negative vote, and the same answer gets accepted and gets positive votes.